# ClassLoader classes are not properly loaded in the thread

Tags: java, jar, jboss, casting, classloader

I am creating a new classLoader using URLClassLoader and trying to set it as the classLoader for the current thread.
But it is not working properly for me.
As per my understanding, if I set a classLoader to the current thread, the methods and interfaces referenced by the Current Thread should be from the present classLoader.
But it is not the case with me. The method is picked up from another jar and I am getting classCastExecption.
Following is the code for getting classLoader:

```
    public ClassLoader getClassLoader(boolean b) {

    ClassLoader loader = null;
    File file = new File(SamVariables.JAR_FILE);
    if (file.exists()){


                try {
            List<URL> urlsList = new ArrayList<URL>();
            urlsList.add(file.toURI().toURL());
            URL[] urls = new URL[urlsList.size()];
            urlsList.toArray(urls);
            URLClassLoader url = new URLClassLoader(urls);


            try { 
                loader = Class.forName("org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory", false, url).getClassLoader();  

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                loader = Class.forName("org.jboss.jms.client.JBossConnectionFactory", false, url).getClassLoader(); 
            }
            } 

        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

    }   
    return loader; // I am successfully getting the classLoader for the class

}

I set it to the current thread

    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(getClassLoader);

But later when I try to get the topicConnectionFactory object, it gives me typecast exception:

topicConnectionFactory = (TopicConnectionFactory) topicConnectionFactObj;
```

It gives me classCastException.

When I checked the TopicConnectionFactory object, it is coming from another jar file which is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As per my understanding, if I set a classLoader to the current thread,
>   the methods and interfaces referenced by the Current Thread should be
>   from the present classLoader.

No, this is a misconception.  The context class loader is not used unless code specifically uses it.  In particular, the context class loader is not used by the JVM (but it is used by specific APIs, such as for finding an XML parser implementation).  Instead, the class loader of the originating class is used.

If you want your code to be able to load classes from a custom class loader, then you must load your classes in that class loader.  For example, put those classes in a separate JAR, put that JAR on the URLClassLoader class path, and use reflection to load/call your class from that URLClassLoader.